# 90's TV; alien ships appear, tell humans to "do better"; turns out they wanted weapons

Tags: story-identification, tv, the-twilight-zone

This story may be from *Outer Limits* or *Twilight Zone*.

A ship appears and overpowers all of Earth's defenses. The aliens say they have seeded life on Earth, and have come back and are disappointed in our development. If we don't do better in 3 days, the earth will be destroyed.

After incredible effort, world peace is achieved. But then it turns out the aliens seeded life to develop weapons and strategies - they wanted us to be more warlike, not less. The Earth is destroyed.

Comment: They seeded Earth a billion years ago, and they're only going to give it three more days? They are disappointed that we couldn't destroy their ship?

Comment: Sooner or later you have to either crap or get off the pot.

Comment: Sooner or later you have to either crap or get off the _plot_ ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was from *The Twilight Zone*, the series that started in 1985. The episode was "A Small Talent For War," aired in January 1986, and is one of my favorites.

From the plot synopsis on Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Small_Talent_for_War):

> An ambassador (John Glover) from an alien race arrives, claiming that his race had genetically engineered the people of Earth. He tells the quarrelsome members of the United Nations Security Council that his race is displeased over Earth's "small talent for war", having failed to produce the potential that the aliens had nurtured. When the ambassador announces that his fleet will destroy all life on Earth, the Security Council pleads for and is granted a 24-hour reprieve to prove Earth's worth. With the survival of humanity at stake, the Security Council and the General Assembly negotiate an accord for lasting global peace and present it to the alien ambassador.
>
> The global peace agreement brings great humour to the emissary. The aliens were, in fact, seeking a greater talent for war, as they had genetically seeded thousands of planets to breed warriors to fight for them across the galaxy