# Looking for title of story of aliens that bred earthlings to be warlike

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name of the story of aliens that bred earthlings to be warlike. When we mistook their requirements and made world peace instead, they decide to destroy us. Ideas?

Comment: Is it a short story, a novel, a episode in a series or a movie?

Comment: Don't know. I was told about it years ago with out the details you request. Always wanted to read it (or watch it) but could never find any referen

Answer (score 13):

This is "A Small Talent for War", an episode from the 1985 version of the television show, "The Twilight Zone".

The episode was written by Carter Scholz and Alan Brennert, and directed by Claudia Weill, and aired on January twenty-fourth, 1986.

The episode's plot had an alien delegation coming to destroy earth because of our "Small talent for war." The Earthlings take this to mean that we are to be destroyed for our warlike nature, and an emergency session of the United Nations creates an overnight peace treaty. Things then end up that the aliens are breeders of warriors, and the earth is a slow-starter, and our breeding program not worth continuing. The alien thanked the United Nations for the laugh that our misunderstanding provided him.

Comment: And if so, this is a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166572/90s-tv-alien-ships-appear-tell-humans-to-do-better-turns-out-they-wanted-w